# Open source software for safe chat

Tags: communication, chat, instant-messaging, parental-control

I would like to find an open source library or service that can **filter inappropriate language** for a chat system targeted at children.

Anyone heard of something like this?

Even just remotely related to this? Just the filtering part?

Thanks!

Emmanuel

Comment: If you want a *service*, SO is the wrong site to help you.  If you want a *library*, then you should probably specify what platform, language, etc.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what language or platform. As long as I can connect to it over the internet. My client is a Flash program but the server can be anything.

Comment: are you looking for something similar to this http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/11/introducing-memchat-open-source-group-chat-framework-in-php-supporting-memcached-apc-sqlite-flat-files-and-mysql/ --> see profanity filter in the flow diagram which is exactly what you are looking for. You can manually add new profane words to be filtered on the fly and chat system will adapt to the newly updated filters.

Comment: The key thing in MemChat is the PHProfanity library which sounds EXACTLY what I wanted. But this project is dead and there are no files I can download. So close but so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to implement this myself. I just couldn't find a good product for this.